# Convert a business application in progres from Silverlight to WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight-4.0

Almost 2 years ago, I asked a question how easy it would be to convert an application from WPF to Silverlight. The result was that I couldn't do it in a few days.

Now we are considering moving in the opposite direction. We have an application that looks like this:

[image: Set up]

So when converting, the server would just stay the same. We don't have any idea what time it would need to make the changes. We figure that we need to redo all Views, but besides that, we don't know for sure what modifications are needed.

Has someone did something similar before? How did you do it? What were pitfalls? And how did you plan it?

Any advice/tips/guidance would be great.

Comment: I would pick and average view and convert it.  You might not get it fully functional due to dependencies but will give you an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that may put a wrench in things is if you're using the async web service calls that are in silverlight you'll have to translate them in WPF because until .Net 4.5 async web calls aren't well supported. (looking for a reference on that fact, if someone has that'd be excellent)

also WPF offers some easier ways to do some of the tasks around binding and data templates which may wish to be explored and may change some of the design

Comment: Thanks, those easier things are the main reasons why we would make the  switch. I also didn't think about the async calls, good you brought it up.

Comment: @djerry Support for the async calling pattern has been in the desktop .Net Framework just as long as it has been in Silverlight. All you have to take care of is to check the "Generate Async Methods" checkbox in the Add Service Reference Dialog. What you are referring to is the new Async CTP Functionality that's part of Net 4.5 which is an entirely different thing.

Comment: @OliverWeichhold: ah, ok good to know, my colleagues and I were wondering what would be different. I think our biggest worry is al XAML related stuff and the mvvm framework we are using.